# dynamic values in narrative text type values for a column in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to add columns values in a narrative text but able to add only one value for every row

```
var hashColDf = rowmaxDF.select("min", "max", "Total")  
val peopleArray = hashColDf.collect.map(r => Map(hashColDf.columns.zip(r.toSeq): _*))
val comstr = "shyam has max and min not Total"
var mapArrayStr  = List[String]()
for(eachrow <- peopleArray){
 mapArrayStr = mapArrayStr :+ eachrow.foldLeft(comstr)((a, b) => a.replaceAllLiterally(b._1, b._2.toString()))
}
for(eachCol <- mapArrayStr){
rowmaxDF = rowmaxDF.withColumn("compCols", lit(eachCol))  
}
}
```

Source Dataframe :

|max|min|TOTAL|
|3  |1  |4    |
|5  |2  |7    |
|7  |3  |10   |
|8  |4  |12   |
|10 |5  |15   |
|10 |5  |15   |

Actual Result:

|max|min|TOTAL|compCols                 |
|3  |1  |4    |shyam has 10 and 5 not 15|
|5  |2  |7    |shyam has 10 and 5 not 15|
|7  |3  |10   |shyam has 10 and 5 not 15|
|8  |4  |12   |shyam has 10 and 5 not 15|
|10 |5  |15   |shyam has 10 and 5 not 15|
|10 |5  |15   |shyam has 10 and 5 not 15|

Expected Result :

|max|min|TOTAL|compCols                 |
|3  |1  |4    |shyam has 3 and 1 not 4  |
|5  |2  |7    |shyam has 5 and 2 not 7  |
|7  |3  |10   |shyam has 7 and 3 not 10 |
|8  |4  |12   |shyam has 8 and 4 not 12 |
|10 |5  |15   |shyam has 10 and 5 not 15|
|10 |5  |15   |shyam has 10 and 5 not 15|

Comment: col3 result should be like this   :  col3--> "the col3 has 2 and 3".. Combination of dynamic string and column values.

Comment: Question is not explained properly. Please provide code snippet and more rows as example.